# Unable to update textview

Tags: android, xml, textview, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to android and got stuck with a small issue. I have a `TextView` element in a `Relativelayout`.And my application is receiving `broadcast` from `GCM` and want to update this `TextView` dynamically according to the `broadcast` received. I have tried to use `TextViewElementId.setText` method. But it doesn't work.

Snippet from layout.xml file

```
<TextView
    style="@style/LabelFont"
    android:id="@+id/txtView1"
    android:text="-"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Snippet from my Activity class(here I pass the appropriate data and text view id to setBroadcastText method)

```
public void setBroadcastText(final String pstrText ,final TextView  tvView){

    handler.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            ptvView.setText(pstrText);
        }
    });
```

}

This setBroadcastText method is called when data relevant to this text box is received.

Do I need to add something to update this textview on runtime?

Comment: Is there an exception or it just doesn't work ?

Comment: Does it break at the `ptvView.setText(pstrText);` line?

Comment: Yea.. there is an exception : null pointer exception. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference. i guess, it refers to tvView as null object reference.  Attempt to invoke virtual method on int android.widget.TextView.getID() on null object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your Handler is null. Therefore it crashes.

Comment: The TextView. android.widget.TextView.getID() is invoking null object reference, i.e the R.id.TextViewId passed in findViewById is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference.
```

This means that the handler is null.
You should initialize the handler object before calling post method like this:

```
handler=new Handler();
```

Comment: Its not the handler that is null. But the TextView.  
android.widget.TextView.getID() is invoking null object reference, i.e the R.id.TextViewId passed in findViewById is null.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of R&D, this is what I figured.
To update the view as and when the broadcast is received, do the following:

in the GCMIntentService class,

```
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
//your code
protected void onMessage(final Context arg0, final Intent arg1) {
//Other parts of your code
Intent broadcast = new Intent("IntentName");
                                broadcast.putExtra("Intent_Key", "Intent_Value");
                                 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(broadcast);
}
```

Now, in the activity class where text view has to be updated, receive this broadcast . Here's how.

```
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
//
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//Other parts of onCreate
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(NewMethodName,
                new IntentFilter("IntentName"));

}
```

Implement your method NewMethodName() as a BroadcastReceiver() method to update your view on runtime.